# Creating ImageFile for photo not working

Tags: java, android, file, android-camera, createfile

I'm writing an app which uses camera. I have encountered a strange problem. The "createImageFile()" creates a file successfully on my Virtual Device with API 16. However when i run the app on my Sony Xperia Z3 (Android 6.0.1, API 23) the file is not created. I don't even get an error. I just click on the button which runs the cameraChoosen() and nothing happens.

After some debbuging, I've created 3 Toasts in createImageFile().

All Toast are working on Virtual Device API 16.

Only Toast1 works on my Xperia Z3

```
    public void cameraChoosen(){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            //...
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.karol.carendal", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Toast1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Toast2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (image.exists()){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Any ideas what is causing the problem?

Regards   :)

Comment: Put a toast in that catch block too. You have that catch. The exception  is also visible in the logcat.

Comment: Also if that catch happens not only display a toast saying so but also return. As it does not make sense to continue with the code then. Display e.getMessage in the toast.

Comment: Further it is bad code as you should not already create a file with File.createTempFile(). Remove it. You should only create a suitable image file path.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 6 and above you should not only request write external storage permission in manifest.

You also need at runtime ask the user to confirm this permission once.

Google for runtime permission.

Alternatively the user of your app can go to the Android settings for your app and toggle the Storage permission switch.